# Reference null in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, symfony

I am trying to put a reference to null but I can not. taking this:

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="alumn", simple=true, nullable=true)
 */
protected $alumn;
```

Can someone tell me how to do something like this ?

```
$class->setAlumn(null);
```

The error is why the method waiting

```
public function setAlumn(\ModelBundle\Document\Alumn $alumn)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a method removeAlumn()

```
public function removeAlumn()
{
    $this->alumn = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal "not behavior". You can compare the DocumentGenerator with EntityGenerator, then search for "nullable".

EntityGenerator ok:

https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/EntityGenerator.php#L1197

DocumentGenerator nop:

https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Tools/DocumentGenerator.php#L652

Maybe you can post an issue on their Github (or better, make a PR!)